# Checking if current time of day is before or after a specific time

Tags: php

I've found plenty of solutions that output a bool if the day is before or after a specific date, but I can't seem to find one about time specifically in PHP.

I've got a script that I want to be available for use between 7:45AM and 3:45PM and only monday through friday - but never before or after these times or on weekends.

I've been racking my brain on how to do this, and I'm posting here because I'm sure there is a very simple way to do this that I am overlooking.

This is what I have so far:

```
$timeOfDay = date("h:iA");
$dayOfDay = date("D");

if(strcmp($dayOfDay,'Mon') != 0
 ||strcmp($dayOfDay,'Tue') != 0
 ||strcmp($dayOfDay,'Wed') != 0
 ||strcmp($dayOfDay,'Thu') != 0
 ||strcmp($dayOfDay,'Fri') != 0) {
    //disable site
 } else {
    //if $timeOfDay is before 7:30AM or after 3:45PM, disable site ELSE enable site
 }
```

To be clear, the script should only be online Monday-Friday between 7:45AM and 3:45PM.

EDIT:
Another note - I am ONLY seeking the PHP logic in which I can get a true or false for, I can handle the rest of the code disabling the script etc.

Comment: Get and compare timestamps

Comment: @u_mulder Timestamps from what? There are no records to compare to. That's what I'm trying to figure out, what I can compare the times from my 2 variables with to create a true or false based on my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$now = strtotime("now");  // here come current timestamp
$dt_start = strtotime(date("d.m.Y 07:45"));  // timestamp of today 07:45
$dt_end = strtotime(date("d.m.Y 15:45"));    // timestamp of today 15:45
$cur_day = date("w", $now);    // number of cur day 0 to 6

if ((0 < $cur_day && $cur_day < 6)             // check what day is it
    && ($dt_start < $now && $now < $dt_end)) {   // check time interval
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: So that if statement is `do stuff` if time is between those 2 times? Or is it the opposite?